# Centrar un enlace

Tags: css

Buenas, no consigo centrar un enlace.

```css
#Anyadir-Rutina-btn {
  background-color: #21211d;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="Power-Contenedor">

  <a href="#" id="Anyadir-Rutina-btn"> Añadir entreno </a>

</div>
```

¿Cual es el motivo por el que no me deja?

Salud

Comment: El principal motivo es que no tiene ninguna propiedad que intente centrar el elemento por lo tanto no se podría responder el _(por qué no lo deja)_ . Para centrar quizá bastaría con agregar un `position: relative;left: 50%;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplemente deberías de asignarle la propiedad `text-align: center` a tu contenedor para que centre el enlace, ya que este es un elemento `inline`.

**ACLARACIÓN:** *Al coger los elementos de bloque (`display: block`) el 100% de la anchura disponible por defecto, en este caso no te hará falta definirle una anchura ya que cogerá el 100% de la anchura de la página.*

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```css
#Power-Contenedor{
  text-align: center;
}

#Anyadir-Rutina-btn {
  background-color: #21211d;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="Power-Contenedor">
  <a href="#" id="Anyadir-Rutina-btn"> Añadir entreno </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Debe definir un ancho al contenedor `#Power-Contenedor`, y luego si lo centras.

```css
#Power-Contenedor{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#Anyadir-Rutina-btn {
  background-color: #21211d;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="Power-Contenedor">

  <a href="#" id="Anyadir-Rutina-btn"> Añadir entreno </a>

</div>
```